# Why does MSVC++11 rejects constexpr qualification of a function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, constexpr

So, playing around with constexpr, MSVC (Visual Studio 2012) gave me an error while trying to qualify my function with the `constexpr` keyword using this simple program (includes omitted):

```
constexpr int factorial(int n)
{
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : (n * factorial(n-1));
}

int main(void)
{
    const int fact_three = factorial(3);
    std::cout << fact_three << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`constexpr` was underlined red with the following message:

> Error : this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

and trying to compile the program gave the following output:

> 1>main.cpp(5): error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';'
>
> 1>main.cpp(5): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

It really puzzles me as it is the very example that Cppreference [uses to illustrate the use of `constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr). At first I used a simple function that returned a literal, i.e. `constexpr int func(){return 5;}`, but which yielded the same error. I interpreted the first message as "it should be a member function of a struct or class", but the example from Cppreference shows that it's not necessary apparently.

So, what am I obviously missing here ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Quite simply - because Visual Studio doesn't support `constexpr` (prior to [Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn956974.aspx)).

Note that MSVC++11 is Visual Studio 2012; VC++10 is Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Oh, didn't think of that... Thanks for pointing it out ! I'll keep that link, and accept asap. I don't understand the downvote though...

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question containing the code that didn't work, what you expected it to do, and the error you were getting.

Comment: I agree, the question's fine. In fact, I'll just go and upvote it myself.

Comment: @Chowlett: Keep us informed! :)

Comment: Just a small note:  the link in the answer still says that MSVC doesn't support `constexpr`, but since the [Visual C++ Compiler November 2013 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-the-visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp.aspx), MSVC++12 now supports it partly (still not supported for member functions).

Comment: @JBL From what I can tell, MS only lists a feature as being supported if it's properly supported; otherwise, it's marked as only partial support, or as not supported.  (For example, VC++10 _technically_ supports `char16_t` and `char32_t`... as typedefs of `unsigned short` and `unsigned int`, respectively, in `yvals.h`.  It rightly lists them as not supported.)  The full list of supported features appears to be at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#top