# compilation error using constexpr in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use constexpr in C++ but get the compile error: 'constexpr' was not declared in this scope.

I tried both in CodeBlocks using the GNU GCC compiler, and in Visual Studio 2013.

the code is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    constexpr double ft2m = 0.3048;
    std::cout << ft2m;
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Which version of GCC?

Comment: Also, [partial duplicate here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20264644/440558) (regarding VS2013).

Comment: I'm going guess that you need to change your compiler settings so that it compiles against the C++11 standard.

Comment: I've "finished" the code snippet so it compiles.

Answer (score 2):

What version of gcc are you using?

You might need at -std=c++11 to your command line

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that MSVC2013 does not support `constexpr`. It does not purport to implement the C++11 standard.

The first version that does is MSVC2015.

Your `constexpr` statement is grammatically correct C++11. Make sure you have a GCC version compliant with that standard.