# static constexpr member in-class initialization

Tags: visual-c++, constexpr, visual-c++-2013, in-class-initialization

Could anyone help me find out what is wrong with in-class initialization of 
static constexpr member varaible like in the code below ?

Using Visual Studio 2013

```
struct hg {
public:
    static constexpr float asd = 9.0f;
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The above code gives the following errors :

Error  1

```
error C2144: syntax error : 'float' should be preceded by ';'
```

Error   2

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: `constexpr` not available in [`vs2013`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264644/constexpr-not-compiling-in-vc2013)

Comment: Ok. Is the only workaround this : static const float asd() {return 9.0f;}